# jquery mobile input masking not working

Tags: html, jquery-mobile, formatting, jquery-mask

I am trying to mask SSN input using jquery mask plugin, however it doesn't seem to play well with jquery mobile. The code is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/YKUba/). Appreciate any help.

If this doesnt work, what are the alternatives?

Also copied the code for reference below:

Scripts:

```
jquery.mobile-1.0.1.min.css
jquery-1.6.4.min.js 
jquery.mobile-1.0.1.min.js

$("#ssnprimary").mask("999-99-9999");
```

HTML:

```
  <div data-role="page" id="mainpage">
    <div data-role="header">
      <h1> My Test </h1>
    </div><!-- /header -->

    <div data-role="content">
      <div class="content-primary">
        <form id="fmain" data-ajax="false">
          <!-- Primary SSN -->

          <div data-role="none">
            <label for="ssnprimary">SSN:</label> 
            <input type="tel" name="ssnprimary" id="ssnprimary" value="" />
          </div>
          </form>
         <br />
       </div><!-- /content -->
    </div><!-- /content -->

    <div data-role="footer"
      data-theme="d"></div><!-- /footer -->
  </div><!-- /page one -->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not include the [Javascript](http://jquery-joshbush.googlecode.com/files/jquery.maskedinput-1.2.2.js) for the jQuery plugin to mask inputs.

I tried editing your fiddle but it is not showing the result. So I created a new fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7MhAU/

Comment: Thanks, I did have it in my code and forgot to put it in fiddle. However, I just realized that I was calling the mask globally instead of pageshow and hence was not taking into affect as the DOM tree was not loaded by JQM.

Answer (score 1):

If using "Masked Input plugin for jQuery" from digitalbush.com the problem is **the mobile device's browser is not triggering the keydown and/or keypress events the plugin relies on**. Using the built-in browser on my Android 2.3 device and typing with the digital keyboard has no effect. The cursor just sits at the start of the input box and blinks.