# Masked inputs with PhoneGap on Android

Tags: cordova, jquery-mobile, jquery-mask

I'm using jQuery Mobile + PhoneGap to build my first mobile app and I need to apply `<input />` masks. For that I'm trying to use jQuery's [Masked Input plugin](http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/), which I'd used on desktop browsers and just works. But Android's 4.0 browser used on PhoneGap seems to have weird issues with that plugin:

- Using `<input type="text" />` it works, but that type of input shows alphanumeric keyboard, which is not useful;
- Using `<input type="number" />` we got the numeric keyboard, but it looses all typed characters;
- Using `<input type="tel" />` we got the numeric keyboard and it seems to works, but behaves unexpectedly.

In the end, neither option seems to fit my needs. Is there any other alternative to use `<input />` masks with jQuery Mobile + PhoneGap on Android? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used masked inputs but try using [jqxMaskedInput widget](https://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-demo/demos/jqxmaskedinput/index.htm) which has support for `jqm` and mobile browsers.

Also have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9170661/jquery-mobile-input-masking-not-working) question. Hope this helps.